# Scope of static variables

Tags: php, static-methods

Can someone explain to me why a static variable called dynamically to a page does not display the assigned values.

For the test I created 3 files.

1) test_scope_1.php : This file has the class with static methods/variables.

2) test_scope_2.php : contains the call to a method from above class to output the contents.

3) test_scope_render.php : this will assign the variables to the class in file 1 and out put the contents from the class, have a container to replace the dom element when a button is clicked, and at the end output generated from file 2.

Basically the initial out put and the output from the second file is displayed correctly with correct number of elements in the array but when the button is clicked to dynamically load the array, it returns 0. According to my understanding, these values somehow went out of scope but aren't static variables be accessible from anywhere?

Here are the contents of the first file.

1) test_scope_1.php

```
class ScopeTest
{
    private static $sample_array=array();
    public static function push($value)
    {
        self::$sample_array[]=$value;
    }
    public static function render()
    {
        echo "ARRAY COUNT ".count(self::$sample_array);
        foreach (self::$sample_array as $index=>$value)
        {
            echo "INDEX=>".$index." VALUE=>".$value;
        }
    }
}
```

2) test_scope_2.php

```
include_once "test_scope_1.php";
echo "This is another file test_scope_2.php<br>";
echo ScopeTest::render();
```

3) test_scope_render.php

```
<?php 
    ScopeTest::push(12);
    ScopeTest::push(15);
    ScopeTest::push(13);
    ScopeTest::push(14);
    ScopeTest::push(27);
    //This outputs the above entries
    ScopeTest::render();
    //This as well outputs the above entries with array count
    include_once "test_scope_2.php";
?>
//The problem arises here when the button is clicked
clicking on the button will get all the array from above from ajax call.
<button id='the_bomb'>click for magic</button>
<div id='replace_this' style='color:red'>
    This will be replaced.
</div>
```

Here is the output image, the order of the output displayed do not match with the code posted here, the second output and the third is interchanged.
[image: Image of the output]

Comment: I'm still confused as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Just testing out the scope of static variable and trying to figure out why these values do not work when the same file is called with Ajax. I am just curious regarding this topic.

Comment: PHP manual on the static keyword, see [THIS](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) page.

Comment: I dare say you're not using AJAX unless you're using Asynchronous Javascript And XML (or JSON, for that matter).
Just reloading a PHP page is _not_ AJAX.